# How can I log an ArrayIndex out of bound in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logging

I have the array `var john = ['asas','gggg','ggg'];`

If I access `john` at index 3, ie. `john[3]`, it fails.

How can I display a message or alert saying that there is no value at that index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function checkIndex(arrayVal, index){
    if(arrayVal[index] == undefined){
        alert('index '+index+' is undefined!');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
//use it like so:
if(checkIndex(john, 3)) {/*index exists and do something with it*/}
else {/*index DOES NOT EXIST*/}
```

Comment: dont try to cast the type! use === instead of ==  ! It'll be faster as well (by nanoseconds, but hey! :)

Comment: "Array index out of bounds" and "array has 'undefined' element" should be handled differently. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728424/array-out-of-bounds-comparison-with-undefined-or-length-check

Answer (score 6):

```
if (typeof yourArray[undefinedIndex] === "undefined") {
  // It's undefined
  console.log("Undefined index: " + undefinedIndex;
}
```

Comment: His question:
**how can i display a message or alert saying that there is no value for the index passed.**

Comment: "Array index out of bounds" and "array has 'undefined' element" should be handled differently. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728424/array-out-of-bounds-comparison-with-undefined-or-length-check

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has try catch

```
try
  {
  //your code
  }
catch(err)
  {
  //handle the error - err i think also has an exact message in it.
alert("Error");
  }
```

Comment: Or check the length of the array.

Comment: if(somearray.length < 3 ) { then do something }

Comment: It is a crappy solution to catch index out of error and just swallow it. This kind of programming leads to bugs. It is better to just check the length of the array!

Comment: Javascript doesn't throw an exception when you access an out of bounds value. So, I'm not clear how this at all answers the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript arrays start at 0. so your array contains contents 0 - 'asas', 1 - 'gggg', 2 - 'ggg'.

Answer (score 1):

```
var john = ['asas','gggg','ggg'];
var index=3;
if (john[index] != undefined ){
 console.log(john[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indexed starting with 0, not 1.

There are 3 elements in the array; they are:

```
john[0] // asas
john[1] // gggg
john[2] // ggg
```