# Check inside a loop that array has next element in Javascript/QML

Tags: javascript, qml

I have an array `items`. I need to make sure that in the current iteration of the loop I can safely call the next item of the array

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

  // do some stuff with current index e.g....
  item = items[i];


   // then do something with item @ i+1
   if(items[i+1]) {
      //do stuff 
   }

}
```

Is this how it is done or if not how/what would be the better way?

P.S. I do not want to do a bound check

Comment: The best way would be to replace `i < items.length` with `i < items.length-1`. Then, you can safely call `items[i+1]` inside your loop.

Comment: @blex That should be an answer

Comment: @meagar I don't feel like posting it as an answer, but please do, if you think it deserves it ;)

Comment: @blex thanks that's a neat trick...but `if(items[i+1])` can be considered safe or not?

Comment: `if(items[i+1])` is not very safe, if, for example, your array contains any _falsey_ values, like `false`, `""` or `0` (your condition won't be met, the `if` statement won't be executed). A better way to check that _there is_ an element at index `i+1` would be to do `if(i<items.length-1)`.

Comment: take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728424/array-out-of-bounds-comparision-with-undefined-or-length-check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to loop through every element except the last one (which doesn't have an element after it), you should do as suggested:

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length-1; ++i) {
    // items[i+1] will always exist inside this loop
}
```

If, however, you want to loop through every element -even the last one-, and just add a condition if there is an element after, just move that same condition inside your loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    // do stuff on every element
    if(i < items.length-1){
        // items[i+1] will always exist inside this condition
    }
}
```

---

`if(items[i+1])` will return false (and not execute the condition) if the next element contains a falsey value like `false`, `0`, `""` (an empty String returns `false`).

Answer (score 4):

Put a value check on variable `i`  and make sure it is less than `items.length-1` in order to safely access `items[i+1]`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length-1; ++i) {

  if(items[i+1]) {
    //do stuff 
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually, i needed to break the loop between an if and an else, your answer helps a lot because one can't break array.forEach in a goog way like the old fashion loop for does

Answer (score 4):

Drop the `for` loop and use [`array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and simply check whether a next value exists:

```
items.forEach(function (item, index) {

  if (!items[index + 1]) return;

  // do something with item and items[index + 1]
});
```